# Emacs skeleton works in one buffer, but not in the other

Tags: emacs

I have a skeleton defined like this

```
  (define-skeleton mp-apt-title
    "Insert an apt title" nil
    '(setq str (skeleton-read "Title? "))
    '(when (string= str "") (setq str " no title "))
    '(setq parameters (list str (getenv "USER") (format-time-string "%e. %B %Y")))
    '(setq lengths (mapcar 'length parameters))
    '(setq maxl (+ 6 (max (nth 0 lengths) (nth 1 lengths) (nth 2 lengths))))
    '(setq seperator (make-string maxl ?-))
    > seperator \n
    > (nth 0 parameters) \n
    > seperator \n
    > (nth 1 parameters) \n
    > seperator \n
    > (nth 2 parameters) \n
    > \n
    )
```

In the file where it is defined i try out the skeleton via M-x mp-apt-title and it works fine. If i switch buffer and try it again i am asked "Title ?". I enter title and then the response: "Wrong type argument: number-or-marker-p, nil".

What do i miss?

matthias

Comment: For me it works in another buffer as well. In what buffer are you trying to execute it?

Comment: What I would try is to remove text from the bottom up, to see where the problem originates from.

Comment: hi Dualinity. Thanks for your comments. Using "Instrument function for debugging" (should have tried this earlier, but sometimes i am just blocked from obvious things) I found the reason already: The "other buffer's" mode defined a buggy indentation function. And this function's call was triggered by the skeletons '>'